# <Viewport3D>: Hidden element identification

Tags: c#, wpf, parent, children, viewport3d

I have a XAML layout:

```
<f:FlipPanel x:Name="flipper" Height="90" Width="90">
    <f:FlipPanel.Front>
        <Canvas x:Name="Empty_Frame" Visibility="Visible">
            <Path Stroke="#FFBCC2AB" StrokeThickness="2">
                <Path.Data>
                    <GeometryGroup FillRule="EvenOdd">

                    ... <!-- There are a lot of geometric elements -->

        </Canvas>
    </f:FlipPanel.Front>
    <f:FlipPanel.Back>

    ... <!-- There are a lot of geometric elements -->

    </f:FlipPanel.Back>
    </f:FlipPanel>
```

FlipPanel is a complex component taken from a third-party library. During execution, I need to replace the `<Canvas>` with another set of elements. 
"Search-delete" code does not work:

```
var ecanvas = flipper.Children.OfType<Canvas>().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "Empty_Frame");
flipper.Children.Remove(ecanvas);
```

The reason lies in the hidden intermediate element `<Viewport3D>`, which is located on the panel.

Question: How can I get a link to this hidden element to work with it (add and remove elements)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how *FlipPanel* works, but actually you don't add Canvas to its Children collection, but put it to *FlipPanel*'s 'Front' property. If you want to remove canvas, try the following:

```
flipper.Front = null;
```

And in order to put a new element there:

```
flipper.Front = myNewElement;
```

Comment: First command works. On the second I get an error. "Must disconnect specified child from current parent Visual before attaching to new parent Visual." myNewElement is already contained in the grid. Сan it be freed from the parent? Or should it be re-created in the code С#?

Comment: An element can have only 1 parent (can only be a child of 1 element). So you should remove it from the Grid's Children collection first: myGrid.Children.Remove(myElement)